# Adding directives to an element using the compile function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a simple directive to avoid having bulky elements for hovering. This is what I have:

```
app.directive('ngHover', function(){
  return {
    compile: function($element,attr) {
      $element.attr('ng-mouseenter',attr.ngHover + ' = true')
              .attr('ng-mouseleave',attr.ngHover + ' = false')
              .removeAttr('ng-hover');
    }
  }
})
```

The resulting element is what I would have wrote (and would have worked) but it doesn't seem to be added before angular uses `$compile`. I could use `$compile` manually but I want to understand why this doesn't work.

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/B1s2WKmyVDqCyWiftEUV?p=preview)

Comment: When you add directives to the same element dynamically (like you're doing here), it's too late - your element is being compiled and the attributes that are on it are already cached. There's no point in adding them - they won't get compiled. Based on what you are trying to do,I would create a custom directive that *does not* use other directives. It's like you're writing ngHover and manipulating the DOM in your link function. See how ngMouseenter is implemented in angular source, and model that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the [compiler of Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler) works.

> Compiler is an Angular service which traverses the DOM looking for
>   attributes. The compilation process happens in two phases.
>
> Compile: traverse the DOM and collect all of the directives. The
>   result is a linking function.
>
> Link: combine the directives with a scope and produce a live view...

Which means that by the time when you are inside of compile function where you add the attributes, it's over and compiler will never discover and recognise `ng-mouseenter` and `ng-mouseleave` as directives. In order to achieve this you will need to trigger another round of compilation with `$compile`, as you said.

Also see [this message](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/dHfK1cq0ohk/vE19bHm_-KgJ) and the whole thread. There you can see that it would work if you were setting extra directives on children of the current element, but not on itself.